# Accessing lists of dictionaries and merge dictionaries with the same key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

The lists of dictionaries below is a short cutout of my dataset. Each list contains the data measured at one station. Every measured value is then put inside a separate dictionary. The original dataset contains many more stations and many more dictionaries per station.

```
results =[[{'value': 14.6,'timestamp_measured': '2017-12-31T20:00:00+00:00',
            'station_number': 'NL1','formula': 'PM10'}, 
            {'value': 16.6, 'timestamp_measured': '2017-12-31T21:00:00+00:00',
             'station_number': 'NL1', 'formula': 'PM10'}],
            [{'value': 27.2, 'timestamp_measured': '2017-12-31T20:00:00+00:00',
              'station_number': 'NL2','formula': 'PM10'},
            {'value': 19.0, 'timestamp_measured': '2017-12-31T21:00:00+00:00',
             'station_number': 'NL2','formula': 'PM10'}]]
```

Instead of having a separate dictionary for each measured value, I want to have only 1 dictionary per 'station_number' which contains the 'formula' and a list of all the measured values:

```
results = {'station_number': 'NL1', 'formula': 'PM10', 'value': [14.6, 16.6]},
          {'station_number': 'NL2', 'formula':'PM10', 'value': [27.2, 19.0]},
```

What would be a pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with what you want to get: A dictionary of stations, where the value of each station is a dictionary containing a list for the `value` from each report. So collect the constant part first, then gather the values in a list:

```
new_stations = dict()

for station in results:
    # Copy the fixed info
    fixed = station[0]
    name = fixed["station_number"]
    this_station = { "formula": fixed["formula"], 
                     "station_number": name,
                     "value": []
                   }
    # Now collect the values
    for record in station:
        this_station["value"].append(record["value"])

    # Save the station in our main dict
    new_stations[name] = this_station
```

Answer (score 0):

```
stations = {}
for lst in results:
    for d in lst:
        if d['station_number'] not in stations:
            stations[d['station_number']] = {
                'formula': d['formula'],
                'timestamp_measured': [], 
                'value': []
            }
        stations[d['station_number']]['timestamp_measured'].append(d['timestamp_measured'])
        stations[d['station_number']]['value'].append(d['value'])
```

Keys are station numbers, so this:

```
for k, v in stations.items():
    print('{}:\n{}'.format(k, v))
```

will print:

```
NL1:
{'formula': 'PM10', 'timestamp_measured': ['2017-12-31T20:00:00+00:00', '2017-12-31T21:00:00+00:00'], 'value': [14.6, 16.6]}
NL2:
{'formula': 'PM10', 'timestamp_measured': ['2017-12-31T20:00:00+00:00', '2017-12-31T21:00:00+00:00'], 'value': [27.2, 19.0]}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Your print result is indeed what I am looking for. However, something I perhaps did not clarify in my question is that there are many more dictionaries per station.

Comment: do all similar station numbers have the same 'formula'?

Comment: There are multiple 'formulas', but I think I will download and store those separately to save myself some trouble. So the answer to your question would be Yes